# Can't install theme in Wordpress ? Option is disabled

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I just started using wordpress.

I have configured the basics of installation.

But now I want to install a theme but the option is disabled.

What should I change.

I have already changed the permission of themes and plugins folder.

Comment: Do you have an option to install plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Solved
I had to enter this line in my wp-config.php file

```
    define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
    define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

It worked. It overrules the requirement of sftp credentials.